# Remote mysql database connection

Tags: mysql

if php uses the following server name `mysqlxx.90` and the username ouxxxxxxch to connect successfully to the local database and the server IP is `1x.xx.xx.x8`, what would I usually enter as the server name to connect remotely.

Confusing question... I can connect properly to the database through ssh and command line, could it be that I'm just being blocked remotely, and how would I prove this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the server IP to connect. Obviously, port 3306 will need to be open to connections and your MySQL username and password must be accepted by the server.

You can try

```
telnet <serverip> 3306
```

on the command line to see if you can connect to the server on port 3306.